# Theme: ThemeData() Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use Theme but don't know what i'm doing wrong the color didn't change.need help :

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.green),
    );
  }
```

Comment: where do you want to see this changes?

Comment: @eamirho3ein in the appBar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `appBarTheme: AppBarTheme()`, then do the changes as you like.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     theme: ThemeData(appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.green, elevation: 15)),
    );
  }
```